# How to reference proper non-generic overload in c#?

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

What do i write instead of ??????? to select proper overload?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class A {}

    class B : A {}

    class C : A {}

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var l1 = new List<C>();
            var l2 = new List<C>();
            Comparer<C>(l1, l2, ???????);
        }

        void Compare(C a, C b) { }

        void Compare(B a, B b) {}

        void Compare<T>(IList<T> a, IList<T> b, Action<T,T> comparator)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
                comparator(a[i], b[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to make the methods static and fix the method name. You can even use type inference on the initial call to `Compare`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var l1 = new List<C>();
    var l2 = new List<C>();

    Compare(l1, l2, Compare);
}

static void Compare(C a, C b) {}

static void Compare(B a, B b) {}

static void Compare<T>(IList<T> a, IList<T> b, Action<T,T> comparator)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        comparator(a[i], b[i]);
}
```

In this case there's no ambiguity - `Compare(C, C)` is the only method in the group which is convertible to an `Action<C, C>`. If you had a `Compare(A, A)` method, the more specific method would still be picked. You'd get ambiguity if instead you had:

```
static void Compare(A a, C b) {}
static void Compare(C a, A b) {}
```

However, I would *strongly* recommend that in cases like this you try to avoid overloading where possible. Give the methods distinct names - it'll make it a lot easier to read, and avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to do with the values.  If you just want to pass a delegate you could do the following

```
Comparer<C>(l1,l2, (left,right) => {});
```

In this case, the <C> part can actually be left off.  The compiler will be able to infer the parameters.

I am curious about your choice of `Action<T,T>` for the parameter named comparer.  Comparison functions typically return a value which represents the result of comparing two values.  The `Action<T,T>` type just returns void.  It should likely be either

1. Changed to `Func<T,T,int>` which is a more standard signature for a comparison function
2. Change the parameter name to something more indicitive of a function that doesn't return a value.  Like del, action or func.